# Loop until a specific user input is received in Python

Tags: python, loops

Hello Im doing a assessment for school. Im quite a newbie to python and I really have no idea on how to loop this

```
    achieved=50 #predefined variables for grade input

merit=70

excellence=85

max=100
import re #imports re an external modeule which defines re
studentfname = input("Input Student first name in lowercase")
if any( [ i>'z' or i<'a' for i in studentfname]):#checks if is in lowercase letters
    print ("Invalid input must be letter and in lowercase")
    import re
studentlname = input("Input Student last name in lowercase")
if any( [ i>'z' or i<'a' for i in studentlname]):
    print ("Invalid input must be letter and in lowercase")
    import sys
    raise SystemExit
    print(studentfname)
elif len(studentlname)>30:
    print ("Very long string") 
    raise SystemExit
    import re
teacherfname = input("Input your first name in lowercase")
if any( [ i>'z' or i<'a' for i in teacherfname]):
    print ("Invalid input must be letter and in lowercase")
    import sys
    raise SystemExit
    print(teacherfname)
elif len(teacherfname)>30:
    print ("Very long string") 
    raise SystemExit
    print(teacherfname)
teacherlname = input("Input your last name in lowercase")
if any( [ i>'z' or i<'a' for i in teacherlname]):
    print ("Invalid input must be letter and in lowercase")
    import sys
    raise SystemExit
    print(teacherlname)
elif len(teacherlname)>30:
    print ("Very long string") 
    raise SystemExit
    print(teachercode)
teachercode = input("Input your teacher code in lowercase")
if any( [ i>'z' or i<'a' for i in teachercode]):
    print ("Invalid input must be letter and in lowercase")
    import sys
    raise SystemExit
    print(teachercode)
elif len(teachercode)>30:
    print ("Very long string") 
    raise SystemExit
    print(teachercode)

while True: #inputs student depending on the input prints out results id achieved, merit and excellence
 try:
    grade = int(input("Enter student's grade"))

    print(str(grade))
    break
 except ValueError: 

  continue
#prints if not a number stops letters
if grade >merit>excellence>= achieved: 
 print("Achieved")
if grade < achieved:
    print("not achieved")
if grade >=merit>excellence < excellence:
    print("merit")
if grade >= excellence > merit:
    print("excellence")
if grade < 0:
    print("can't be negative")
    raise SystemExit
if grade > max:
   print("Cannot be more than 100")
   raise SystemExit
print("student's details")#last print of variablesa
print(studentfname,studentlname)
print("teacher's details")
print(teacherfname,teacherlname,teachercode)
print("student's grade")
print(grade)
if grade >merit>excellence>= achieved: 
 print("Achieved")
if grade < achieved:
    print("not achieved")
if grade >=merit>excellence < excellence:
    print("merit")
if grade >= excellence > merit:
    print("excellence")
if grade < 0:
    print("can't be negative")
    raise SystemExit
if grade > max:
   print("Cannot be more than 100")
   raise SystemExit
print("Thanks for adding in the grades")

        break
```

Im trying to make it so that it will ask the user if they would like to input more student data after they have done one student. eg like if they wish to continue and basically repeat the coding again. I would really love some help

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. We need a minimal working code to help you

Comment: Put the whole thing in a `while True:` loop. Then `if input('enter more?')=='no': break`.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question what you need is to loop until a given input is given.
So you would use:

```
while True:    # infinite loop
    user_input = raw_input("Want to continue? ")
    if user_input == "No":
        break  # stops the loop
    else:
        # do whatever computations you need
```

Answer (score 0):

You just loop it

```
achieved=50 #predefined variables for grade input

merit=70

excellence=85

max=100
import sys
import re #imports re an external modeule which defines re
while(1):
    studentfname = input("Input Student first name in lowercase")
    if any( [ i>'z' or i<'a' for i in studentfname]):#checks if is in lowercase letters
        print ("Invalid input must be letter and in lowercase")
        raise SystemExit
    print(studentfname)
    studentlname = input("Input Student last name in lowercase")
    if any( [ i>'z' or i<'a' for i in studentlname]):
        print ("Invalid input must be letter and in lowercase")
        raise SystemExit
    elif len(studentlname)>30:
        print ("Very long string")
        raise SystemExit
    print(studentlname)
    teacherfname = input("Input your first name in lowercase")
    if any( [ i>'z' or i<'a' for i in teacherfname]):
        print ("Invalid input must be letter and in lowercase")
        raise SystemExit
    elif len(teacherfname)>30:
        print ("Very long string")
        raise SystemExit
    print(teacherfname)
    teacherlname = input("Input your last name in lowercase")
    if any( [ i>'z' or i<'a' for i in teacherlname]):
        print ("Invalid input must be letter and in lowercase")
        raise SystemExit
    elif len(teacherlname)>30:
        print ("Very long string")
        raise SystemExit
    print(teacherlname)
    teachercode = input("Input your teacher code in lowercase")
    if any( [ i>'z' or i<'a' for i in teachercode]):
        print ("Invalid input must be letter and in lowercase")
        raise SystemExit
    elif len(teachercode)>30:
        print ("Very long string")
        raise SystemExit
    print(teachercode)
    while True: #inputs student depending on the input prints out results id achieved, merit and excellence
        try:
            grade = int(input("Enter student's grade"))
            print(str(grade))
        except ValueError:
            continue
        if grade >merit>excellence>= achieved:
            graden = "Achieved"
            print("Achieved")
        if grade < achieved:
            print("not achieved")
        if grade >=merit>excellence < excellence:
            graden = "merit"
            print("merit")
        if grade >= excellence > merit:
            graden = "excellence"
            print("excellence")
        if grade < 0:
            print("can't be negative")
            raise SystemExit
        if grade > max:
            print("Cannot be more than 100")
            raise SystemExit
        print(grade)
        print("Student")
        print(studentfname)
        print(studentlname)
        print("Teacher")
        print(teacherfname)
        print(teacherlname)
        print(teachercode)
        print("Grade")
        print(str(grade))
        print(graden)
        print("Thanks for adding in the grades")
        break
    if input('More?')=='no': break
```

Now it works. Just remember quotation marks in input. Or fix it.

Comment: Hey. Thanks I have tried the code that you gave. but it doesn't display any of the outputs for example before it would state the students name teachers name and what grade they got but now its just skipping all of that and asks for more. Could you please help thanks :)

Comment: Ok, try now again.

Comment: hey I tried it again and its doing this Input Student first name in lowercase james
james
Input Student last name in lowercase smith
smith
Input your first name in lowercase jerry
jerry
Input your last name in lowercase cake
cake
Input your teacher code in lowercase nl
nl
Enter student's grade 89
89
More?  when its meant to be something like this

Comment: Input Student first name in lowercase larry
larry
Input Student last name in lowercase the
Input your first name in lowercase king
Input your last name in lowercase pin
Input your teacher code in lowercase nl
Enter student's grade 89
89
excellence
student's details
larry the
teacher's details
king pin nl
student's grade
89
excellence
Thanks for adding in the grades
=> None

Comment: so after all the inputs it displays everything like that. Really sorry for distributing you this much but thanks

Comment: Hey thanks its kind of fixed right now. Im really sorry that it breaks ur heart but I utterly most appreciate what you are doing as I am quite the newb and I cant thank you enough. Just a minor error in that it is repeating it twice Enter student's grade 89
89
excellence
student's details
james smith
teacher's details
kato kie pi
student's grade
89
excellence
Student
james
smith
Teacher
kato
kie
pi
Grade
89
excellence
Thanks for adding in the grades
More? Thanks again

Comment: OḲ. Removed doubles. If you want to change how it prints just edit lines after "print("Student")"

We are kind of offtopic now.

Answer (score 0):

i have come across the same issue and managed to fix it an easier way while not having to change any of your code to much, for example lets say you want a question to be asked until user inputs "yes":

```
print ("Question here")
Input = input("").lower() 
if Input == "yes":
    break
    nextcode() //optional
else:
    while Input != "yes":
    print ("Question here")
    Input = input("").lower()
    if Input == "back":
        break
        nextcode() //optional
```

this works best if you have a clear function and clear the screen before asking the question so it dose not stack up.
if this dose not work get rid of break and just do nextcode()